# What is this red substance, what to do about it?

Tags: paint

I need help identifying  a red substance i found on some concrete after removing some kitchen cabinets.

I tried to clean it with tissue and water but it only just smudged into the whole floor.

Should I just cover it with the new floor or try to remove/clean it.

If it’s advisable to clean it up then how should I clean it, it seems to spread and smudge except for the first pic where it looks like goo.  Come to think of it there could be two different substances, if so, I’m asking about both.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brick dust? Sweep it up? Vacuum?

Comment: Looks like Paprika... someone was cooking in there.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what it is and it doesn't matter if you clean it or cover it as long as it doesn't stick up in the way.   Clean it, don't clean it.   It is not integral to install a new flooring.   It is some kind of dust or paint.

It looks like the workers were using that area to do "something".   This could be cutting brick, painting, cutting something else, making a really good "red" chili.   Sitting cabinets on it seemed to do the trick the first time.   Being that it has been there a while I am thinking cleaning it will be a mess and maybe not achievable without effecting the surface.